# Express validator returning value : undefined msg: 'Invalid value'

Tags: javascript, express, request, postman, express-validator

Routes

```
const express = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');

const logControllers = require('../controllers/log-controllers');


const router = express.Router();

router.post('/',
    [
      check('title')
         .not()
         .isEmpty()
    ],
    logControllers.createLogEntry
);
```

logControllers

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
const { validationResult } = require('express-validator');
const HttpError = require('../models/http-error');

let DUMMY_LOGENTRIES = [
    {
        id: "j1",
        title: "king"}]

const createLogEntry = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        console.log(errors);
        throw new HttpError('Invalid inputs passed, please check your data.', 422);
    }
    const { title } = req.body;
    const createdLogEntry =
    //new logEntry(
    {
        id: uuid(), title  
    };
    DUMMY_LOGENTRIES.push(createdLogEntry);
    res.status(201).json({ logEntry: createdLogEntry });
};
```

When I remove validators, POST request works, but with the validator Nodemon returns:

```
  formatter: [Function: formatter],
  errors: [
    {
      value: undefined,
      msg: 'Invalid value',
      param: 'title',
      location: 'body'
    },
```

**Bonus question:** Without the validator the returned response is only the uuid... not the title and I can't figure out why since I ask for the full createdLogEntry which should return title and uuid. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find what was missing in terms of the validator, but I did find that I was returning text instead of JSON in Postman.  Just rewrote everything and it worked.  Guessing it was syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by restructuring the order of the middleware

Comment: please be more specific. What is the better/correct order?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).